# interpolate mode in d3 js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, data-visualization

Hi I trying to generate line in d3 js with interpolate mode according to this sample
http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093025. And I come up with the code below

```
    var line=d3.svg.line().interpolate('step')
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

but it seems does not work when I try to update the links which will be connecting to the nodes using json data

```
    // Update the link
    var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
        .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

    // Enter new links here
    link.enter().insert("path", "g")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", function(d) {
            var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
            return line({source: o, target: o});
    })  
    .transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", line);
```

Can any one give me a hint

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it doesn't work? Note that the line generator expects an array of points, but you have an object with source and target if I see this correctly.

Comment: vertical and horizontal lines not display with my code. They should display as an indented tree

Comment: Can you show us the complete code?